# How to keep the xml-stylesheet?

Tags: python, xml

I want to keep the xml-stylesheet. But it doesn't work.
I use Python to modify the XML for deploy hadoop automatically.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
　　　　<name>fs.default.name</name>
　　　　<value>hdfs://c11:9000</value>
　　</property>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree as ET

def modify_core_site(namenode_hostname):
    tree = ET()
    tree.parse("pkg/core-site.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()
    for p in root.iter("property"):
        name = p.find("name").text
        if name == "fs.default.name":
            text = "hdfs://%s:9000" % namenode_hostname
            p.find("value").text = text
    tree.write("pkg/tmp.xml", encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)

modify_core_site("c80")
```

Result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<configuration>
    <property>
　　　　<name>fs.default.name</name>
　　　　<value>hdfs://c80:9000</value>
　　</property>
</configuration>
```

The xml-stylesheet disappear... 
How can I keep this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is you can use [lxml](http://lxml.de/installation.html) Once you parse xml go till you find the xsl node. Quick sample below:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> doc = lxml.etree.parse('C:/downloads/xmltest.xml')
>>> root = doc.getroot()
>>> xslnode=root.getprevious().getprevious()
>>> xslnode
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
```

Make sure you put in some exception handling and check if the node indeed exists. You can check if the node is xslt processing instruction by

```
>>> isinstance(xslnode, lxml.etree._XSLTProcessingInstruction)
True
```